# How to setup products with multiple pricing components like MonthlyFee & InitialSetup?

Tags: product

we are a SaaS-vendor and offer our cloud-hosted software as well as services around this. All these software-access or services consist of multiple pricing components.
Standard is a `MonthlyFee` or `PeriodicFee` and an initial `SetupFee`.
There are products like Online-Marketing Services that also have a third component like a `CampaignBudget`.

How am I supposed to implement these services using SF-products?
AFAIK the product is supposed to have one and only price that is only constrained/changed by the Price Books.

So am I supposed to create a dedicated Product for each pricing component?
Like:

1. SoftwareSetupFee
2. SoftwarePeriodicFee

How do I 'bundle' these products into 'One Service' that can be added as a whole to the Opportunity?

Additionally, a Pricing Component like the `OnlineMarketingCampaignBudget` is actually a customer-defined and changing budget (and also something we profit from based on a non-negotiable, fixed percentage).

Any advice highly appreciated

Comment: just FYI, we introduced zuora and integrated it with salesforce successfully. having different `Charges` is not possible with the salesforce products per se.